Can I remove a rule from a built-in function?
Can I remove the rule DiracDelta[n x]==DiracDelta[x]/n when n is numeric from the definition of DiracDelta? Can I see all the rules for this symbol and delete the ones I dislike?

To modify build-in functions is very dangerous. I advise you to define your own myDiracDelta. You can convert myDiracDelta to DiracDelta by using Replace.

Also, to get better help, it would help if you explain your actual underlying computation and the problem you are trying to solve. Otherwise, it is not clear why you would just want to remove certain rules. You can also use Inactive[DiracDelta][5 x].
